# OCaml CSV module - ERROR: Unbound Module Csv

Tags: ocaml

I have installed the OCaml CSV module in C:\OCaml\lib. When I run the following code in the top level `open Csv;;`

I receive the error message `Error: Unbound module Csv`

I am not sure why the module is not loading. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution. I did not compile the csv.ml and csv.mli files.

If anybody else has this problem here are the steps to fix the problem:
1) In the command line go to the OCaml\lib directory where your .ml and .mli files are located
2) Run the commands `ocamlc -c modulename.mli` and `ocamlc -c modulename.ml`

in the toplevel you can now run `open modulename;;`

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps involved. First you need to make sure that CSV loaded into your toplevel, then you can open it. I don't use windows, but under OS X it looks like this:

```
$ ocaml
    OCaml version 4.00.1

# #load "unix.cma";;
# open Unix;;
# stat;;
- : string -> Unix.stats = <fun>
#
```